# Sendgrid C# bulk email X-SMTPAPI header not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sendgrid

I am trying to send email with SendGrid to multiple recipients in an ASP.Net C# web application

According to the SendGrid documentation I need to add X-SMTPAPI header to my message in JSON formatted string. I do so, for first check I just added a hand-typed string before building my json email list progamatically here is my code:

```
string header  = "{\"to\": [\"emailaddress2\",\"emailaddress3\"], \"sub\": { \"%name%\": [\"Ben\",\"Joe\"]},\"filters\": { \"footer\": { \"settings\": { \"enable\": 1,\"text/plain\": \"Thank you for your business\"}}}}";

        string header2 = Regex.Replace(header, "(.{72})", "$1" + Environment.NewLine);

        var myMessage3 = new SendGridMessage();

        myMessage3.From = new MailAddress("emailaddress1", "FromName");
        myMessage3.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", header2);
        myMessage3.AddTo("emailaddress4");
        myMessage3.Subject = "Test subject";
        myMessage3.Html = "Test message";
        myMessage3.EnableClickTracking(true);

        // Create credentials, specifying your user name and password.
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxx"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxx"]);

        // Create an Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email, which returns an awaitable task.
        transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage3);
```

But it just seems to ignore my header, and sends the email to the one email "emailaddress4" used in "addto".
According the documentation if the header JSON is parsed wrongly, then SendGrid sends an email about the error to the email address set in "FROM" field, but I get no email about any error.

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 2):

For me using the latest 9.x c# library the only way I could solve this was by using the MailHelper static functions like this:

```
var client = new SendGridClient(HttpClient, new SendGridClientOptions { ApiKey = _sendGridApiKey, HttpErrorAsException = true });

            SendGridMessage mailMsg;
            var recipients = to.Split(',').Select((email) => new EmailAddress(email)).ToList();
            if (recipients.Count() > 1)
            {
                mailMsg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(
                new EmailAddress(from),
                recipients,
                subject,
                "",
                body);
            }
            else
            {
                mailMsg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(
                new EmailAddress(from),
                recipients.First(),
                subject,
                "",
                body);

            }

            if (attachment != null)
            {
                mailMsg.AddAttachment(attachment.Name,
                                  attachment.ContentStream.ToBase64(),
                                  attachment.ContentType.MediaType);
            }

            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(mailMsg).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _log.Trace($"'{subject}' email to '{to}' queued");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                throw new HttpRequestException($"'{subject}' email to '{to}' not queued");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't recieve any errors at your FROM address, but your JSON contains the following flaws:

- , near the end makes the string invalid json
- spaces around the first % in %name%, that might make sendgrid think it's an invalid substitution tag
- if you use the X-SMTPAPI header to specify multiple recipients, you are not supposed to add a standard SMTP `TO` using AddTo().

Besides that, you didn't wrap the header at 72 characters (see the [example](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/using_the_smtp_api.html) in the documentation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but basically, it is not around the JSON, since I validated that before asking the question here. It was just mistyped. I updated the code above...

As far as I saw in the docs the standard SMTP TO is required parameter and needs to be valid. 

I also added the line wrapping, nothing changed, simply nothing happens with my X-SMTPAPI header

Answer (score 0):

I figured that however the X-SMTPAPI documentation talks about passing the header as JSON, the API itself expects it as a parameter, containing Ienumerable string. So the working code is:

```
var myMessage3 = new SendGridMessage();           


        myMessage3.From = new MailAddress("email4@email.com", "Test Sender");

        myMessage3.AddTo("email2@email.com");
        myMessage3.Subject = "Új klubkártya regisztrálva";
        myMessage3.Html = "Teszt üzenet";
        myMessage3.EnableClickTracking(true);

        /* SMTP API
             * ===================================================*/
        // Recipients


        var addresses = new[]{

           "email2@email.com", "email3@email.com"

            };

        //string check = string.Join(",", addresses);


        myMessage3.Header.SetTo(addresses);


        // Create credentials, specifying your user name and password.
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxxxx"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxxxxxx"]);

        // Create an Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email, which returns an awaitable task.
        transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage3);
```